# Selection Bug using jQuery

Tags: jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".lower_it").click(function() {
        $("#" + this.id).toggleClass("active")
        $("#" + this.id).siblings(".itemContainer").toggleClass("hide")     
        $(".itemContainer").not("#" + this.id).removeClass("active");
        return false;
    });
});
```

Demo - http://jsfiddle.net/JKnjz/60/

The stripes at the bottom are the navigation buttons 1, 2, 3. They effect the boxes at the top.

- red = active
- 10 width = collapsed
- 100x100 = default position,

I would like all previous positions to collapse when activating a different box. If you play around with the demo, you can notice how it jumbles up the sequence.

[edit]

Sorry I didn't mention this earlier. My main project requires me to use two different divs using using their own class, but the buttons and effected boxes share the same id's. Which is why I am using ("#" + this.id). It is already working in the demo.

Comment: Instead of `$("#" + this.id)` you should really be using just `$(this)` to reference the current object

Comment: Sorry I didn't mention this earlier. My main project requires me to use two different divs using separate class's, but the buttons and effected boxes share the same id's. Which is already working in the demo.

Comment: Why is this a "*bug in jquery*"? Shouldn't the question title be "...bug in my code which is using jquery" ?

Comment: yes. the bug is in my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**first of all IDS should be unique** ... you have 2 elements with same id...
best way to get what you need is to use **data html5 attribute**..and `$.data()` to get the particular data attribute.

```
 <div>
   <div id="lol1" class="itemContainer">1</div>
   <div id="lol2" class="itemContainer">2</div>
   <div id="lol3" class="itemContainer">3</div>
  </div>
 <div>
 <div data-id="lol1" class="lower_it">1</div>
 <div data-id="lol2" class="lower_it">2</div>
 <div data-id="lol3" class="lower_it">3</div>
```

with out changing most of your core logic..

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".lower_it").click(function() {
    $("#" + $(this).data('id')).toggleClass("active").removeClass("hide"); //<---remove class hide
    $("#" + $(this).data('id')).siblings().addClass("hide")   //<--addclass hide to all siblings.
    $(".itemContainer").not("#" + $(this).data('id')).removeClass("active");
    return false;
  });
});
```

[fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/bipen/JKnjz/61/)

However, you have to add CSS to ass the background color to the loser_it divs...add class to all the divs... this is just an example you can modify the CSS as you required.

[update fiddle with Css](http://jsfiddle.net/bipen/JKnjz/64/)